Schema registry taking old schema id while decoding
We have written Kafka consumer using in Node.js using KafkaJS library. And using @kafkajs/confluent-schema-registry to deserialize the message.
After initializing schema registry, If I call registry.decode method to decode I facing "ConfluentSchemaRegistryValidationError: invalid payload\n    at JsonSchema.validatePayload  error.
Also If I console registry after initialisation, Its taking older schema ID.
SchemaRegistry {
  cacheMissRequests: {},
  api: {
    _manifest: Manifest {
      host: 'abc', //dummy data**your text**
      allowResourceHostOverride: false,
      parameterEncoder: [Function: encodeURIComponent],
      bodyAttr: undefined,
      headersAttr: undefined,
      authAttr: undefined,
      timeoutAttr: undefined,
      hostAttr: undefined,
      clientId: 'Confluent_Schema_Registry',
      gatewayConfigs: [Object],
      resources: [Object],
      context: {},
      middleware: [Array]
    },
    Schema: { find: [Function: resourceMethod] },
    Subject: {
      all: [Function: resourceMethod],
      latestVersion: [Function: resourceMethod],
      version: [Function: resourceMethod],
      registered: [Function: resourceMethod],
      config: [Function: resourceMethod],
      updateConfig: [Function: resourceMethod],
      register: [Function: resourceMethod],
      compatible: [Function: resourceMethod]
    }
  },
  cache: Cache {
    getLatestRegistryId: [Function (anonymous)],
    setLatestRegistryId: [Function (anonymous)],
    getSchema: [Function (anonymous)],
    setSchema: [Function (anonymous)],
    clear: [Function (anonymous)],
    registryIdBySubject: {},
    **schemasByRegistryId: { '100248': [Object] }**
  },
  options: { JSON: { ajvInstance: [Ajv] } }
}

How can make registry to take latest schema and decode message using latest schema.
Also is there a way to decode message using local schema?
